# Обнаружение человека на изображении

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, теория

Как можно подступиться к решению задачи, по поводу обнаружения человека на изображении и выделения области где он находится. Я примерно представляю что нужна нейронная сеть, которая на выходе. Будeт выдавать 4 координаты области, внутри которой будет находиться человек. Но я не до конца понимаю как обучать такую нейросеть и какую структуру она должна иметь.

Comment: Это задача сегментации + классификации. Поищите информацию по ключевым словам "нейронные сети сегментация изображений". Дальше, думаю, разберётесь. Руководств в сети очень много и в виде текстов и в виде роликов на ютьюбе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, данная задача - задача семантической сегментации/object detection. В основном практически все нейросети, которые работают с изображениями основаны на свёртке(CNN). Архитектур подобных нейросетей очень много. К примеру: `R-CNN, Yolo, Mask RCNN`. Можно конечно написать архитектуру таких моделей самому, но я думаю для начала Вам будет достаточно просто взять готовую реализацию из фреймворков, таких как `tensorflow` или `pytorch`.
К вопросу о том, как это обучать. Очевидно вам нужен датасет. Датасет представляет из себя набор пар: изображение - координаты bounding box с человеком. Т.е. каждой картинке у вас есть соответствующие координаты прямоугольника внутри которого есть человек. Для того, чтобы разметить такой датасет можно использовать различные программы, такие как LabelIMG. Они позволят упростить процесс разметки. Но, справедливости ради, задача поиска человека на фото не новая, и в открытом доступе вы можете найти уже размеченные датасеты. Их стоит поискать на [kaggle.com](https://kaggle.com).
Вот некоторые ссылки, касающиеся поиска объектов на изображении.
[Офф. документация PyTorch с вашей задачей](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html)

[Обучение на готовом датасете COCO](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/08/02/pytorch-object-detection-with-pre-trained-networks/)

[На Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection)

[Очень подробно про разметку и обучение, tensorflow](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html)

[Простое объяснение о работе CNN](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/introduction-to-how-cnns-work-77e0e4cde99b)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ